# Use unsupported USB footswitch?

Tags: usb, mouse, driver

I am attempting to use this footswitch:

http://www.scythe-usa.com/product/input/008/usbfootswitch_detail.html

They only support windows, and USB Overdrive apparently doesn't support it either.

I want to use it to click the mouse in OSX.

Is there a software that will allow this configuration?

Comment: It doesn't need any drivers under Windows, so I wonder why it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Oh, it "works" it comes out of the box asigned to the keyboard keys '1', '2', and '3'.
However, I want to assign it to the mouse buttons, and this has thus-far proven impossible, (they also don't accept returns for this item :\   )

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have an issue with usb footswitch I am trying to get working under mavericks http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140732/sending-controlleft-command-with-external-footswitch-delcom-only-picking-up-c

Comment: No it was never resolved, someone needs to write a driver for it. :(

Answer (score -1):

Runs the setup software under Windows. The pedal stores the settings itself.