# Sending control+left command with external footswitch, delcom, only picking up control

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-source

This is a kind of specific question but I have a delcom usb programmable footswitch PN 803620-5m

This is the updated model http://www.delcomproducts.com/productdetails.asp?PartNumber=703600-5M

I have it programmed to send the left control key signal.  I have verified it is sending the correct signal using [key codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/)

[image]

THe top highlighted part of the above image is the usb controller input, and the bottom part is my left control key on my keyboard, its working great so far.  THe issue is when holding control and hitting left button, the keyboard doesn't register the left command seperatly, it seems like osx knows it is a command and is running the command macro.  (the command cntrl+left moves spaces to the left for me)

When I try the same thing with my usb input it logs the left arrow as a seperate key press NOT as a compound command.  [image]In the image above it logs the left arrow key ,but when using the keyboard to do control left the left is not registered.

Does anyone know how to have osx recognize my external usb controller switch as a compound command?

Comment: I just found usboverdrive but it is not detection the input of my usb device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

oh boy, from kinesis [website][4]

> Note: Modifier actions from one USB device
>   cannot modify the input of a second USB device due to limitations
>   designed into the Apple operating system. Example: Shift, Control,
>   Command, or Option keystrokes programmed into the footswitch cannot
>   modify the input of a separate USB keyboard or mouse. However, a key
>   sequence like ‘Cmd-W’ or ‘Cmd-Shift-left arrow’ will work on a
>   Macintosh if the entire sequence of keystrokes has been pre-programmed
>   into the footswitch. (Footswitch can only be programmed on a Windows
>   PC).

I just tried this using my usb keyboard and built in osx keyboard and it seems to be true.  I can hit control + left on my usb keyboard and it works fine but control on my usb keyboard + left on the builtin keyboard does not work:(

Great news! Karbiner is a mature open source project that allows modifing across devices as a feature.
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en

> Share state of modifier keys with all connected keyboards: When you
>   are using multiple keyboards, modifier keys are shared with all
>   keyboards. For example, pressing "shift key on keyboard1" and "space
>   key on keyboard2" sends shift-space.